# Cannot Limit Connections With Iptables: "No chain/target/match by that name."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I am trying to limit the the number of connections to my Ubuntu server to no more than 10 in the most recent 50 seconds for any individual IP.  I am trying to do this with iptables.  I have never configured or entered any iptables command before.  The commands fail thusly:

```
# /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i venet0:0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
# /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i venet0:0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 50 --hitcount 10 -j "DROP"
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

venet0:0 is indeed an interface:

```
# ifconfig | head -20
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:160410 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160410 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:10303872 (10.3 MB)  TX bytes:10303872 (10.3 MB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:63699988 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44836148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:61862863168 (61.8 GB)  TX bytes:4519224195 (4.5 GB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:*.*.*.*  P-t-P:*.*.*.*  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Comment: Does any iptables command work? If not, then you need to look at your kernel config to ensure netfilter works properly. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679749/how-to-fix-iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name) SO question for details.

Comment: venet0:0 doesn't appear to have an ip address associated with it.

Comment: It does.  I purposely obscured it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this format instead, assuming *.*.*.* is the ip address for venet0:0

```
-i venet0 -d *.*.*.*
```